# I am getting an unexpected output while exporting my dictionary to csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I was taking data from a table through beautiful-soup  and want to paste it's output in a csv file. Suppose i want data from 1 to 10, But my csv file shows the last value only, i.e 9th. And my header is also typed repeatedly in every output. Please see my code and show me where i am wrong. 
However my code has no *errors*, but it is producing data in a strange manner in terminal and printing just only the last value of data in csv file. : (

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame


max = 100500
i = 100002
while i < max:
    page = requests.get(
        "https://rajasthanpuc.in/P_test.aspx?Spuc=P379RJ14" + str(i) + "&flag=1")
    i = i + 1

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    num = soup.find(id='Cmobile_lbl').get_text()
    num2 = soup.find(id='Vechno_lbl').get_text()
    num3 = soup.find(id='Pucc_lbl').get_text()
    num4 = soup.find(id='customername_lbl').get_text()
    num5 = soup.find(id='Regyear_lbl').get_text()
    num6 = soup.find(id='vehtype_lbl').get_text()
    num7 = soup.find(id='EngType_lbl').get_text()
    num8 = soup.find(id='Make_lbl').get_text()
    num9 = soup.find(id='Model_lbl').get_text()
    num10 = soup.find(id='Fuel_lbl').get_text()
    num11 = soup.find(id='TestDate_lbl').get_text()
    num12 = soup.find(id='TestTime_lbl').get_text()
    num13 = soup.find(id='validdate_lbl').get_text()
    num16 = soup.find(id='licence_lbl').get_text()
    num17 = soup.find(id='txtResult').get_text()


# print(text)

    df = DataFrame({
        'numbers______': [num],
        'vehicle_no___': [num2],
        'fuel___': [num10],
        'Pucc___': [num3],
        'regn_________': [num5],
        'model________________': [num9],
        'name_________________': [num4]
    })

    print(df)

    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\intel\Desktop\export_dataframe.csv',
              index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Move **`print(df)`** outside the loop. This will prevent printing the header over and over.

Finally, use the different file mode when writing the csv to file. According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), the **[`df.to_csv(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv)** method can accept a **`mode`** parameter and defaults to **`w`**.

> **mode** : str
>
> - Python write mode, default ‘w’.

So change the mode to something [*else*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) like **`a`** which will open the file for appending without first truncating it.

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\intel\Desktop\export_dataframe.csv',
          mode='a', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot @smac89, but only one thing worked, that is writing my file to csv. But it is again and again printing the header in csv. Can you please provide the code...